# Transpose rows to columns in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

How can I transpose a Dataframe table with only one column and multiple rows like:

```
1
2
3
5
6
7
...
```

to a dataframe with only one row and multiple columns like:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply do a [`pivot`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.pivot):

```py
df = spark.range(10)

df.show()
+---+                                                                           
| id|
+---+
|  0|
|  1|
|  2|
|  3|
|  4|
|  5|
|  6|
|  7|
|  8|
|  9|
+---+


df.groupBy().pivot("id").count().show()                                                                            
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+                                       
|  0|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  1|  1|  1|  1|  1|  1|  1|  1|  1|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

df.groupBy().pivot("id").agg(F.first(F.col("id"))).show()                                                          
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+                                       
|  0|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, but I want to have just one row, your two approaches returns 2 rows

Comment: I need a column for each number, and only one row

Comment: Nope. My two approches show 1 header and 1 row. The content of the row depends on the agg function you use.

Comment: I need to achieve the exact reverse of this - I have one row with few cols and need to convert each of the cols in diff rows.. pivot doesnt seem to help.. any ideas ?